# Crashlytics.Instance.Crash() only working in the MainActivity on Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, wpf, xamarin, crashlytics

I implemented **Firebase Crashlytics** for my **Xamarin.Android** project and it is initializing successfully. I want to simulate a crash and to do so I am using this method provided by the Google Firebase doc : **Crashlytics.Instance.Crash()**.

In the *OnCreate()* method (*MainActivity.cs*), it is **working well**, the app is crashing with this output :

```
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

08-01 13:37:39.871 I/CrashlyticsCore(11105): Crashlytics report upload complete: 5D4322C5001F-0001-2A26-0D16997749AA
08-01 13:37:48.162 W/Fabric  (11105): Could not call getAdvertisingIdInfo on com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient
08-01 13:37:48.163 W/Fabric  (11105): Could not call getId on com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info
08-01 13:37:50.784 D/Mono    (11105): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib64/liblog.so'.
08-01 13:37:50.786 D/Mono    (11105): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib64/liblog.so'.
08-01 13:37:50.786 D/Mono    (11105): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib64/liblog.so' ('/system/lib64/liblog.so').
08-01 13:37:50.786 D/Mono    (11105): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
08-01 13:37:50.786 D/Mono    (11105): Probing '__android_log_print'.
08-01 13:37:50.787 D/Mono    (11105): Found as '__android_log_print'.
08-01 13:37:50.799 I/MonoDroid(11105): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105): Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=10
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <286213b9e14c442ba8d8d94cc9dbec8e>:0 
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <286213b9e14c442ba8d8d94cc9dbec8e>:0 
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):   at Crashlytics.Crashlytics.Crash () [0x0000a] in <114e650c181c4522b75b2d021c6a77a9>:0 
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):   at Umbrella.Analytics.Samples.Uno.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00021] in C:\P\Umbrella.Analytics\samples\uno\Umbrella.Analytics.Samples.Uno.Android\MainActivity.cs:50 
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <95d915721ad748108ff096dce8f8f32c>:0 
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.29(intptr,intptr,intptr)
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException stack trace ---
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=10
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashTest.indexOutOfBounds(CrashTest.java:30)
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.crash(CrashlyticsCore.java:622)
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.crash(Crashlytics.java:323)
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at md5bffa4c77a6a1bb63fef79da9565e62ab.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at md5bffa4c77a6a1bb63fef79da9565e62ab.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
08-01 13:37:50.832 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1293)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
08-01 13:37:50.833 I/MonoDroid(11105): 
08-01 13:37:50.841 D/Mono    (11105): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics[0x76fd86f480] -> System[0x76f0263d80]: 6
08-01 13:37:50.843 D/Mono    (11105): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics[0x76fd86f480] -> System.Core[0x76fd91b000]: 7
08-01 13:37:50.973 W/ics.samples.un(11105): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md5bcaacea39e485ed8e3d7f0e2edda77a7.MonoException
08-01 13:37:50.973 W/ics.samples.un(11105): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md5bcaacea39e485ed8e3d7f0e2edda77a7.MonoExceptionHelper
08-01 13:37:51.071 I/FA      (11105): Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
08-01 13:37:51.158 D/Mono    (11105): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-01 13:37:51.158 D/Mono    (11105): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method_a'.
08-01 13:37:51.158 D/Mono    (11105): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method_a'.
08-01 13:37:51.158 D/Mono    (11105): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method_a'.
08-01 13:37:51.222 I/CrashlyticsCore(11105): Crashlytics report upload complete: 5D4323620097-0001-2B61-0D16997749AA
08-01 13:37:51.623 D/Mono    (11105): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x76fd8acd00] -> System[0x76f0263d80]: 7
Unhandled Exception:

Crashlytics.MonoExceptionHelper: (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) length=2; index=10

08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105): Process: com.nventive.umbrella.analytics.samples.uno, PID: 11105
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105): md5bcaacea39e485ed8e3d7f0e2edda77a7.MonoExceptionHelper: (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) length=2; index=10
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod(Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args)[0x00069](Java/Interop/JniEnvironmentInstanceMethods0x00069.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod(System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters)[0x0002a](Java/Interop/JniPeerMembersJniInstanceMethods0x0002a.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at Crashlytics.Crashlytics.Crash()[0x0000a](Crashlytics/Crashlytics0x0000a.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at Umbrella.Analytics.Samples.Uno.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle bundle)[0x00021](C:\P\Umbrella.Analytics\samples\uno\Umbrella.Analytics.Samples.Uno.Android\MainActivity.cs:50)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_(System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState)[0x00011](Android/App/Activity0x00011.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.29(intptr,intptr,intptr).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at   --- End of managed Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException stack trace ---.(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=10.(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashTest.indexOutOfBounds(CrashTest.java:30).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.crash(CrashlyticsCore.java:622).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.crash(Crashlytics.java:323).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at md5bffa4c77a6a1bb63fef79da9565e62ab.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at md5bffa4c77a6a1bb63fef79da9565e62ab.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1293).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493).(unknown.cs:1)
08-01 13:37:52.208 E/AndroidRuntime(11105):     at  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870).(unknown.cs:1)
```

Now I want to implement it in ViewModel page so via a button click the app will crash. But calling Crashlytics.Instance.Crash() in the ViewModel doesn't make the app crash and I get the following error :

```
[0:] Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=10
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <286213b9e14c442ba8d8d94cc9dbec8e>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <286213b9e14c442ba8d8d94cc9dbec8e>:0 
  at Crashlytics.Crashlytics.Crash () [0x0000a] in <114e650c181c4522b75b2d021c6a77a9>:0 
  at Umbrella.Analytics.Samples.Uno.FirebasePage+FirebasePageViewModel+<CrashlyticsCrashTest>d__18.MoveNext () [0x00028] in C:\P\Umbrella.Analytics\samples\uno\Umbrella.Analytics.Samples.Uno.Shared\FirebasePage.xaml.cs:167 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at nVentive.Umbrella.Client.Commands.AsyncCommandBuilder2Extensions+<>c__DisplayClass12_0+<<Execute>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x00028] in C:\agent\_work\49\s\src\Umbrella.Presentation\Commands\CommandBuilder2Extensions.cs:140 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at nVentive.Umbrella.Client.Commands.ReactiveAsyncCommand`2+<ExecuteInternal>d__34[TParam,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00088] in C:\agent\_work\49\s\src\Umbrella.Presentation\Commands\ReactiveCommand.cs:271 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException stack trace ---
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=10
    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashTest.indexOutOfBounds(CrashTest.java:30)
    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.crash(CrashlyticsCore.java:622)
    at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.crash(Crashlytics.java:323)
```

What do you thing is causing that ? For me it seems it's something related to the main thread.

Thank you

Comment: You said that you implement Crashlytics.Instance.Crash() in ViewModel page, it crash? Can you show some code here about this?